# How to prevent elements from hiding behind transparent actionbar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have a problem with my layout. I use ViewPager tab layout in my app and I would like to use transparent action bar. I managed to prevent the elements from hiding behind action bar, but the problem is that elements sill hide behind the tabs bar. How to fix it?

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:background="#E3F6CE">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try to add a margin top to your Layout?

Comment: @joao2fast4u I added padding to top of the layout and it works partially. I think that the resolution would be to twice this padding, but don't know how to make it in XML file.

Comment: I don't see any padding in your layout. Could you please show the viewpager layout?

Answer (score 1):

Use `CoordinatorLayout` to wrap all components and use this  `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` in your RelativeLayout where `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`